# PHP won't return a response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

It's probably something really basic but I've been at it for a while and it's not jumping out at me and I guess I'm tired...please help.

I'm trying to create a simple login html page, read it using jquery/ajax and have php verify it. Here are the 2 pieces the javascript/jquery and the php. While firebug seems to correctly report that "message" is being set, nothing comes back as response...what am I doing incorrectly? And if php did report an error, where do I look for it?

---

login.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#loginForm').submit(function(){  
        var usern=$('#username').val();  
        var pword=$('#password').val();  
       $.ajax({  
            url: 'mylogin.php',  
            data: 'action=login&usern='+usern+'&pword='+pword,  
            dataType: 'json',  
            type: 'post',  
            success: function (j) {  
                $('#loginmessage').html(j.msg);  
            },  
       });  
    });  
});`
```

---

mylogin.php

```
<?php   
    $username=$_POST['username'];  
    $password=$_POST['password'];  
    $retval['msg']="in mylogin.php";  
    fb($retval,"return output from login");  
    echo json_encode($retval);  
?>
```

Comment: make sure your [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) level is high enough in PHP so all possible errors are outputted, you'll be able so spot them in the firebug XHR request.

Answer (score 8):

Its very simple you are posting your username as `usern` and password as`pword`

So it should be

```
<?php   
    $username=$_POST['usern'];  
    $password=$_POST['pword'];
```

Comment: aaaaargh...i should have caught that . But, even after I fixed that, nothing seems to be sent in response from php.While it looks like the php code is sending back $retval, the success criteria does not seem to be fulfilled....

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the post variables with the names `usern` and `pword` then trying to access them with `username` and `password`

Answer (score 1):

You are using username and password as the post variables names in the PHP code when you are passing the variable names through as usern and pword in your jquery post.

It should look something like

```
<?php   
    $username=$_POST['usern'];  
    $password=$_POST['pword'];
?>
```

It is important when passing variables to use a standard naming convention, it will help reduce the chance of these issues occuring.

Comment: I know - careless of me! I was fiddling with the variable names in case "username" "password" were somehow reserved  and then forgot about it since I decided to see if I could just pass back a message from PHP to Javascript. No joy - even after I fixed the username/password problem. any clues?